# Textarea auto-height-increase

Tags: html, css, resize, textarea

I have html `<textarea>` and css:

```
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 80px;
  resize: none;
}
```

If there is a lot of text, I want the `<textarea>` to increase it's height till 80px and then show a scrollbar. The problem is that `<textarea>` is `25px`(I don't know why, may be my browser set this property) and when there is a lot of text, it shows a scrollbar after `25px`. Is there anyway to show a scrollbar only after `80px`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You really need js to do this, see example below:

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
var limit = 80; //height limit

textarea.oninput = function() {
  textarea.style.height = "";
  textarea.style.height = Math.min(textarea.scrollHeight, limit) + "px";
};
```

```css
textarea {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: Now this is a good answer, short, sweet, perfect!